# Trying to match multiple words multiple times, any order using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to check if a text contains two or more specific words. The words can be in any order an can show up in the text multiple times but at least once.

If the text is a match I will need to get the information about location of the words.

**Lets say we have the text :**
"Once I went to a store and bought a coke for a dollar and I got another coke for free"

In this example I want to match the words coke and dollar.
So the result should be:
coke   : index 37, lenght 4
dollar : index 48, length 6
coke   : index 84, length 4

**What I have already is this:** (which I think is little bit wrong because it should contain each word at least once so the + should be there instead of the *)

```
(?:(\bcoke\b))\*(?:(\bdollar\b))\*
```

But with that regex the RegEx Buddy highlights all the three words if I ask it to hightlight group 1 and group 2.

But when I run this in C# I won't get any results.

Can you point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible what you want only using regular expressions.
Here is a possible solution using regular expressions and linq:

```
var words = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "coke", "dollar" };
var regex = new Regex(@"\b(?:"+string.Join("|", words)+@")\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var text = @"Once I went to a store and bought a coke 
for a dollar and I got another coke for free";
var grouped = regex.Matches(text)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .GroupBy(m => m.Value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .ToArray();

if (grouped.Length != words.Count)
{
    //not all words were found
}
else
{
    foreach (var g in grouped) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found: " + g.Key);
        foreach (var match in g) 
            Console.WriteLine("    At {0} length {1}", match.Index, match.Length);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Found: coke
    At 36 length 4
    At 72 length 4
Found: dollar
    At 47 length 6
```

Comment: But won't this match when only one of the words exist in the text ? 
Both of the words need to be in the text at least once.

Comment: @Kristinnn oh, I missed that out. I'll remake it. Any of the words (2 coke is fine) or both of the words must be at least one time? You could simply check if matches has a length >= 2.

Comment: Yeah both(all) of the words need to be in the text at least once but can be multiple times so coke can be only once and dollar can be 100 times for example. If one of the words doesn't show up it should match at all.

And remember there can be more words than coke and dollar.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to do what you need only using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, it is pret-tay bad but I think it has a shot at working *and* it is pure RegEx no extra tools.

`(?:^|\W)[cC][oO][kK][eE](?:$|\W)|(?:^|\W)[dD][oO][lL][lL][aA][rR](?:$|\W)`

Get rid of the `\w`'s if you want it to capture `cokeDollar` or `dollarCoKe` etc.